# Parsing JSON 'NaN' value in Go

Tags: json, go, nan

When I try and unmarshal this JSON object from the Microsoft Web Ngram API:

```js
{"backoff": NaN, "cookie": "", "probabilities": [], "words": []}
```

I get the error: "invalid character 'N' looking for beginning of value"

I know that NaN isn't valid JSON but the data isn't mine and I need a way to parse it. 
Is there any easy way to do this in Go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could [replace](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Replace) it with null (or 0 or whatever is acceptable):

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp)
//check err
b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte(":NaN"), []byte(":null"), -1) 

//json.Decode(b)
```

Comment: Hmm I thought that would be really slow but it only increases the runtime by 1.2-1.5x, which is completely fine. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I created [xhhuango/json](https://github.com/xhhuango/json) to support NaN, +Inf, and -Inf. The package forks from Golang SDK encoding/json, so the usage is completely the same as encoding/json.